# How do I find the limit of $\frac{x \cdot \ln(1+x)}{e^{2x}-1}$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, factoring, limits-without-lhopital

How do I find: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \ln(1+x)}{e^{2x}-1}$$  without using L'Hospital.

I know that $$\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{L}{M}, M \neq 0$$

My problem is I get: $M = 0$

I've also tried to factor, but can't to get rid of the denominator.

**Extra question**: Geogebra gets an intersection point between the function and x-axis at $(0,0)$, shouldn't the function be discontinuous since $M = 0$?

### [image: Geogebra]

Comment: Let $g(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x}.$ and $f(x)=\log(1+x).$

Comment: you sure you are not allowed to use l'hopital? (If not please remove the tag)

Comment: @Yanko we haven't learned it in school yet, and this is a school exercise

Comment: @user644361 Alright, I edited your question so it will be clear that you don't want to use l'hopital (not everyone looks at the tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factor the denominator as $(e^x - 1)(e^x + 1)$ (difference of squares) and then you need to know that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1. $$

Which you will have seen when you first encountered the derivative of $e^x$ via first principles. This should look familiar to you:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} e^x = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{x + h} - e^h}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^x(e^{h} - 1)}{h} = e^x \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h} - 1}{h}. $$

Comment: You can also show that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$$ because it is in the form: $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$$ where $a=0$.  So, if $f(x) = e^x$, then $f'(0) = e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Following Thomas Andrew's suggestion in the comments, re-write the expression as
$$\frac{x \ln(1+x)}{e^{2x} - 1} = \frac{\ln (1+x)}{\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x}}.$$

Let's try to evaluate the limit using the division rule for limits on the second expression.  The numerator is continuous, so $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln(1+x) = \ln (1) = 0$.  For the denominator, notice that $e^{2\cdot 0} = 1$, so by the definition of the derivative as a difference quotient
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x} = \left.\frac{d}{dx} e^{2x}\right|_{x = 0} = 2.$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x \ln(1+x)}{e^{2x} - 1} = \frac{\lim_{x\to0} \ln(1+x)}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x}} = \frac{0}{2} = 0.$$

---

**As for the extra question**, it appears Geogebra is somehow computing the limit at $0$.

You are right that evaluating the function gives a $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form, so strictly speaking $f(x) = \frac{x\ln(1+x)}{e^{2x} -1 }$ is undefined at $x = 0$.  But, since $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is defined, we can 'fill in' the missing point $(0,0)$ in the graph to get a graph of a continuous function, which we call the **extension** $\tilde f$:
$$\tilde f(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{x\ln(1+x)}{e^{2x} -1} & x \neq 0\\
  0 & x = 0
\end{cases}$$

Points $a$ where $f$ is undefined but $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ is defined are called [removable discontinuities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html).

Comment: @NewBornMATH That's a common misconception. $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = f'(0)$ by definition; L'Hospital's rule is not required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out,one upvote for that.

Answer (score 3):

### Using L-hospital

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \ln(1+x)}{e^{2x}-1}$$
Now as !
approaches to 0 it is in $\frac{0}{0}$ so just apply 
L'Hospital's rule differentiating numerator and denominator we get

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)+\frac{x}{1+x}}{e^{2x}×2}$$
Which is $0/1=0$

### Without L-hospital

As strants has provided the exact solution just by defination still this also works 
As $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....$$
      $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+....$$
Integrating both sides 
     $$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}....$$
   Similarly $e^{2x}=1+2x+\frac{(2x)^{2}}{2!}+....$
At

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \ln(1+x)}{e^{2x}-1}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{3}...}{1+2x+2x^2}$$ which is clearly $\frac{0}{1}=0$

Comment: (+1). By the way, you can do this a bit more formal using the notation of big oh. (to avoid those dots)

Comment: Well ! Are you talking about those dots after three terms in the expansion ? Please let me know how to use the big oh notion ?

Comment: From your answer you can deduce that $\ln(1+x)=O(x)$ as $x$ convergence to zero (meaning that once you divide by $x$ the term is bounded in a small interval around zero). Clearly this implies that $x\cdot\ln(1+x) = O(x^2)$. On the other hand $e^{2x}=1+O(x)$. So we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{O(x^2)}{1+O(x)} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{e^{2x}-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\cdot\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}\cdot\frac{x}{2}\right)=1\cdot1\cdot0=0.$$